# JDBC: How to deal with wildcards in Java PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

For example if I have:

```
connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users 
                                   WHERE status=? AND otherAttribute=?");
```

Where in some cases I might want a specific status and in others I want all statuses. How can I basically do something like:

```
preparedStatement.setInt(1, mySpecificRequestedStatus);
```

and in other cases:

```
preparedStatement.setInt(1, allStatuses); // wildcard
```

So that I don't have to have multiple PreparedStatements, especially for more complex WHERE clauses in the SELECT statements where the permutations can be higher.

Comment: The only good way is to have multiple PreparedStatements. You can calculate them on-the-fly if there are too many permutations.

Comment: What do you mean by calculate them on the fly if there are too many permutations?

Comment: On-the-fly: StringBuilder and lots of if/else to come up with the SQL to use. Not all possible statements already stored in a text file somewhere.

Comment: Doesn't that makes for some pretty ugly looking code that will be hard to read later?

Comment: Yes, it does ;-( Some kind of QueryBuilder could help (`query = select("users"); if (statusFilter != null) query.withWhereCondition("status", statusFilter)`), so that at least you don't see the SQL itself and have to balance brackets and count bind variables and all that. No library recommendation here, though...

Comment: And I am not too sure the "generic query with masking" reads any easier. It seems to have the exact same number of if/else checks as well to figure out what parameters to set.

Comment: If you are suing an ORM though it gets really easy with Criteria APIs.

Comment: I'm not using an ORM, it's right down to the metal - relatively speaking that is ;) But seriously, an ORM wouldn't really be an advantage in my case for a few reasons. One most of the queries are really complex and start to break down with an ORM. Secondly performance is critical. And lastly, the code is obfuscated, which makes using an ORM that much more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You don't have a choice, you have to pick one or the other as I originally suspected and asked.*

You can either:

1. Create a complex prepared statement with if clauses
2. Create a complex SQL statement which doesn't have the best performance

There really isn't a good solution to this. This is why ORM's exist, to abstract this out. The problem is that ORM introduce other issues/complexities in exchange for simplifying other things.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users 
                               WHERE (status=? OR ?=1) AND otherAttribute=?");
```

The second `?` is for the "all statuses" attribute: set it to `1` if you want to ignore the status; set it to zero if you would like the specific `status` to be considered.

Comment: Don't do this, though, if performance is important. With overly generic queries, the DB has no idea what is going on. Neither will the support staff that has to look at query logs to find and fix slow queries. The only good way is to have multiple PreparedStatements.

Comment: @Thilo Although I would agree that with multiple permutations a query like that would quickly become unmanageable, one or two "mask off" parameters are usually OK.

Comment: Agreed. This also correlates with what you are indexing. Fields that are not going to become relevant in an access path are not going to suffer from masking.

Answer (score 0):

Stephane Grenier,

Why not create a `function or procedure` in database and call `function or procedure` from `java`? This would solve many hassles, would keep your java code neat and of course no hard coding of sql queries.

Regards

Comment: Because sometimes this isn't always feasible depending on your environment.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier Could you kindly give an example of a case that proves that this approach is not always feasible? Thanks

Comment: The most common is political development environment. But beyond that, some SQL systems don't offer stored procedures such as SQLLite, etc.